# Disable compiler warnings with pragma GCC diagnostic in LTO builds

Tags: gcc, pragma, lto

I'm having troubles disabling GCC warnings with LTO-enabled builds:

Some warnings (-Wstrict-overflow, -Wmaybe-uninitialized, ...) are
specified on the command line using the -W option switch for compiling
all files within a project. However, I'd like to disable them just on some specific code locations.

Without LTO mode, "#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored" (along with #pragma
push & pop) works smoothly. However, those pragma declarations seem to be ignored when the compiler is invoked back at link stage (LTO build).

Is there a workaround, or a better way to disable specific warning in
specific code locations?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sounds like [this gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80922).